# Position of rightView UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uitextfield

Is there a way to adjust the position of a rightView on UITextField? I tried setting the frame on the view (set as rightView) but it didn't change anything.

I'd like to avoid making two views, one as the rightView and one as the rightView's subview where I change the subview's position, if possible.

Comment: You tried `[textField.rightView setFrame:someFrame];`? Or maybe `setBounds:`.

Comment: You need to take 2 views for that.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The **right overlay view** is placed in the rectangle returned by the `rightViewRectForBounds`: method of the receiver.

So I suggest you subclass `UITextField` and override this method, something like this:

```
@interface CustomTextField: UITextField

@end

@implementation CustomTextField

// override rightViewRectForBounds method:
- (CGRect)rightViewRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds{
    CGRect rightBounds = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + 10, 0, 30, 44);
    return rightBounds ;
}
```

Comment: Cool. However I found for the right view callout I was better using bounds.size.width - 30 i.e CGRect rightBounds = CGRectMake(bounds.size.width - 30, 0, 30, 50); this way it gets the width of your textfield and minus off that figure to get the padding for the right view

Answer (score 14):

@Puneet Sharma's answer was great but that would give the need to create a class that would subclass `UITextField`, what I did instead was create a UIView that would act as a padding.

> This code works without the need to subclass

Here's my code, although it's written in **Swift 3**

```
// this is the view I want to see on the rightView
let checkImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "check24.png"))
checkImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24)
checkImageView.curveEdges(12)
checkImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

// declare how much padding I want to have
let padding: CGFloat = 6

// create the view that would act as the padding
let rightView = UIView(frame: CGRect(
    x: 0, y: 0, // keep this as 0, 0
    width: checkImageView.frame.width + padding, // add the padding
    height: checkImageView.frame.height)) 
rightView.addSubview(checkImageView)

// set the rightView UIView as the textField's rightView
self.textField.rightViewMode = .whileEditing
self.textField.rightView = rightView
```

What happened here is, that the `rightView` which is a `UIView` that has a transparent colored background which then gave the illusion that there is a padding whereas there is not.

Answer (score 0):

Right Padding you can use as

```
let imageview = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image name"))
imageview.contentMode = .center

let rightPadding: CGFloat = 14 //--- change right padding 
imageview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageview.frame.size.width + rightPadding , height:imageview.frame.size.height)

textField.rightViewMode = .always
textFieldd.rightView = imageview
```