# Show UIImage inside UITextfield, tried but doesn't work

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uitextfield

I am using xcode8.3 and Swift3 in my project.

I have a UITextField in storyboard, I created a IBOutlet in corresponding controller class:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!
```

I would like to show a small image on the right side inside the text field, I found a [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903500/swift-add-icon-image-in-uitextfield) (though it shows image on left side).

THis is what I tried:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let imageView = UIImageView();
        let image = UIImage(named: "my_icon");
        imageView.image = image;

        self.myTextField.rightView = imageView
        self.myTextField.rightViewMode = .always
  }
```

(In xcode **Assets.xcassets** folder I have **my_icon.png, my_icon@2x.png, my_icon@3x.png**)

When I run the code on iPhone, I don't see my_icon showing anywhere in UITextField. I also tried to add the ".png" suffix when loading image  `let image = UIImage(named: "my_icon.png");`, it doesn't help either.

Why the solution in the link doesn't work for me?

Comment: here you have a bunch of information about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903500/swift-add-icon-image-in-uitextfield

Comment: @GIJOW, I have already included this link in my question, like I said, I tried it, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Clarify issues: is `image` nil? Also, You may want also to set a frame for `imageView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issue, it sounds funny but it can cause the issue. I believe your imageView's frame is 0.

So

```
    let imageView = UIImageView();
    let image = UIImage(named: "my_icon");
    imageView.image = image;
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.intrinsicContentSize.width, height: imageView.intrinsicContentSize.height)
    self.myTextField.rightView = imageView
    self.myTextField.rightViewMode = .always
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. BTW, if I want to hide the image later on, is it better to set the rightViewMode to Never or is it better to hide the image?

Comment: @leem-fin : I personally prefer removing the rightView and then setting mode to never but setting the rightView's frame to CGRect.zero works as well.

Comment: Thanks, one more question, how to add some space at the bottom and right of the image ?

Comment: @leem-fin : Did you try setting ContentInset. Setting ContentInset.right and bottom should help. I never tried my self just guessing.

Comment: I don't find function to set ContentInset for either UITextField nor UIImage, what do you mean? Could you be more specific please?

Comment: @leem-fin : You have to create a subclass of textField and then override textRectForBounds I have answered it earlier in SO searching for it gimme a minute Ill post the link

Comment: @leem-fin : Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367502/create-space-at-the-beginning-of-a-uitextfield not mine though :P

Comment: @leem-fin : Finally have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371053/position-of-rightview-uitextfield to add padding to rightView. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks! I will take a close look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Set frame:

```
  imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
```